# Would Karna have become the heir to the throne if he survived the war?

Tags: mahabharata

While Karna swore to protect Duryodhana until his last breath, is it somehow possible that he would have become the king? Or would the secret of him being the eldest brother forever have been a secret? Was there any possibility of him not being killed before Duryodhana died?

Comment: These links may be helpful: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05140.htm & http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05141.htm

Comment: I think this is a valid question.

I believe it would never come to that - Karna surviving the war - because that was not what Krishna wanted.

Before that battle Krishna came to Karna and tried to talk him out of it and even mentioned that Karna would be accepted by Yudhisthira and the Pandavas, but He refused to change to the other side and leave Duryodhana.